# How to make a contact form send a confirmation email to the user?

Tags: php

This is what i have so far..

```
 $full_name = $_REQUEST['full_name'] ;         
 $company = $_REQUEST['company'] ;       
 $abn = $_REQUEST['abn'] ;     
 $customer_number = $_REQUEST['customer_number'] ;     
 $about = $_REQUEST['about'] ;     
 $areacode = $_REQUEST['areacode'] ;     
 $telephone = $_REQUEST['telephone'] ;         
 $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;     
 $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;     
 $body =" Full Name: ".$full_name."\n

Company: ".$company."\n                 
ABN: ".$abn."\n    
Customer Number: ".$customer_number."\n
About: ".$about."\n       
Area Code: ".$areacode."\n      
Telephone: ".$telephone."\n     
Email: ".$email."\n                     
Message: ".$message;

$to = "$email";

 mail( "info@rentforbusiness.com.au", "Contact Us Form", $body, "From: $email" );
```

Comment: And this isn't working... how?

Comment: Send them email just like you're sending yourself an email.

Comment: Have you executed this? Is there any errors thrown by PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Just like you do for yourself.

```
mail($email, "Thanks For Resistering", $a_thank_you_message, "From: info@rentforbusiness.com.au" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a table in database. It should contains fields:

- id (auto increment)
- email
- message
- confirmation

When user posts the form, don't send mail to your email, instead of it you need to create random confirmation code (using [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) for example):

```
$confirmation = uniqid();
```

Then add user email, message text and confirmation code to table and send email to user:

```
$url = "http://".$_POST["SERVER_NAME"].
  "/confirmation.php?confirmation=$confirmation'>";
mail($email, "Confirmation", 
 "Please press the following link to confirm your message: 
 <a href='http://$url'>confirm</a>.");
```

In `confirmation.php` file use `$_GET["confirmation"]` variable, search for matching record in the table, get email and message from it and send this data to your email. You can remove entry from database after it if you want.